# Management of data within ArcGIS Online - Feature layer, feature service, etc

Tags: arcgis-online, web-service

I am running into problems achieving these goals within ArcGIS Online.

I have a map of flood hazard polygons across a state.  I want to publish this map (Shapefile, GDB, have it in several formats) as a web service for others to consume.  I want this state-wide layer to be viewable only, with no editing capabilities, and I want those that I invite into an ArcGIS Online group (that the file will be shared with) to be able to access it through not only ArcGIS online, but ArcMap as well.

Additionally, I want to create several views of this statewide map that are filtered by specific regions. The views will be visible in web maps that are shared with regionally specific groups on ArcGIS Online. I hope to set things up in these web maps that these groups will actually be able to not only view the data, but edit the underlying feature layer as well.

So, the end result of what I have been trying to do is:

1. Publish a feature layer.
2. Turn that feature layer into a hosted web service that is shared within a group who should be able to see the whole state, viewing only, no editing.
3. Create different views of the underlying feature layer, filtered by regions.
4. Share create web maps using those views
5. Share those web maps with different regionally specific groups.

Can someone describe the correct work flow for all of these data needs?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are close to your setup. You will have an organization and will publish your state layer up to ArcGIS Online as a feature layer with editing disabled(You can publish this from ArcMap/Pro/Zipped data. Then you will share that feature layer to a group and the other org members have been invited into that group can view that non-editable feature layer. They will be able to Add that feature layer to ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro.

From the feature layer as well the viewers will be able to export the data through the Map Viewer in ArcGIS Online in their different formats you pointed out http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1CA88C296B3D4C4E94EAB92392DDDC0B.

Create different views of that state data using field or feature definitions and share those to other groups: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D6E1538242B24908B1472154696905D3